# Svelte-way of creating element without defining markup on caller

Tags: svelte

I want to make a growl/notification/toast that stackable but don't want to define any component, is there such way to do that?

```
<script>
import toaster from 'toaster.svelte'

function doToast() {
  toaster.ShowInfo('out')
  toaster.ShowWarning('out')
  toaster.ShowError('out')
}
</script>

<!-- not defining any compnent here -->
<button  on:click={doToast} >show</button>
```

i saw lot of repl all of them must define component markup, like this one:

- https://svelte.dev/repl/2254c3b9b9ba4eeda05d81d2816f6276?version=4.2.5
- https://svelte.dev/repl/46c3c3c8943e4752a380ce019fb99739?version=3.49.0
- https://svelte.dev/repl/0091c8b604b74ed88bb7b6d174504f50?version=3.35.0
- https://svelte.dev/repl/d11f78c338f543c2b9c4ec529009dd4e?version=3.35.0
- https://svelte.dev/repl/b95ce66b0ef34064a34afc5c0249f313?version=4.2.5 --> not alert but modal, also need to define markup
- https://svelte.dev/repl/33fa2b9ce00d44748a08e3b65026cfb2?version=4.2.5 --> import external library, can be put on outer layout html but IDEs might not able to detect this function inside svelte component

Comment: If you don't want to use Svelte to create the toast, then just write some plain old JS that creates the toast with pure HTML, but why?

Comment: i want to use Svelte, i just don't want to spawn it dynamically instead of declaring as markup on each svelte pages I have (1 svelte file will be generated as 1 html page, only svelte components that are not generated as html)

Comment: you *could* do this by writing some js that mounts the component but still - I don't get why you want to do this. you usually either mount a Svelte component at the top level or by including it as a tag. "(1 svelte file will be generated as 1 html page, only components that are not generated as html)" what do you mean by this?

Comment: i'm using this for most of my projects https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa @KTibow

Comment: looks like an easy fix, just add _ to the component name

Comment: yes, that what i do for years

Comment: okay - so just include the toast component in whatever component uses it, and add _ to the toast component. the file won't have the problem since you added _.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the component mount itself in the `context="module"` script if that has not happened before. Though, you would have to make sure to also manually destroy the component again if that is ever required.

E.g.

```html
<!-- Toast.svelte -->
<script context="module">
    import Toast from './Toast.svelte';
    let component = null;

    export function toast(text) {
        if (component == null)
            component = new Toast({ target: document.body });

        component.add(text);
    }
</script>
<script>
    let items = [];
    export function add(text) {
        items = [...items, text];
    }
</script>

<div>
    {#each items as item}<p>{item}</p>{/each}
</div>
```

Usage:

```html
<script>
    import { toast } from './Toast.svelte';
</script>
<button on:click={() => toast('Wah!')}>
    Toast
</button>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ea541d095c9c436ca2de7b6e968677bf?version=4.2.5)